# Drawing in JavaScript / HTML5 using XOR to remove old sprite

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing, xor

I'm building the engine for a tiny game, and right now I have just got a red circle with two little eyes as a main character. I have `keyPress` functions to detect movement, and that works, but I wanted to use something I used a long time ago in QBASIC to remove the character and redraw at a new location: `XOR`

Basically, on keypress this happens:

```
if (code == 39) {
    mainChar.drawChar();
    mainChar.x += 1;
    mainChar.leftEye.x += 1;
    mainChar.rightEye.x += 1;
    mainChar.drawChar();
}
```

I thought drawing the character on the same space, then adjusting the positions and drawing again would remove the first instance and draw a new one. Here is a snippet of my `drawChar` method:

```
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(mainChar.x, mainChar.y, mainChar.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.closePath();
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
```

It's 'sort-of' working, and by 'sort-of' I mean it's not completely erasing the first drawing. Nothing has shifted yet for the first call (and the character has been called on load) so I thought XOR would completely erase the image since their coordinates and everything are identical?

Am I way off base, implementing something slightly wrong, or is there just a much better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you noticed that the un-erased part of your circle is very jaggy?

That's because canvas originally drew your circle with anti-aliasing to visually smooth out the roundness of your circle.

When you XOR the same circle, canvas does not erase the anti-aliasing pixels it originally created.

The same will happen for slanted lines.

Bottom line...XOR will not work until browsers let us turn off anti-aliasing.  This option has been proposed to the powers-that-be.

Until then you might change your drawChar so that you can "erase" a slightly larger circle than you originally drew.

```
drawChar(50,"red");
drawChar(51,"white");

function drawChar(r,fill){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100,100,r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = fill;
  ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That would explain why the image is so... fuzzy. Erasing the character with a white circle would mean having to redraw any background or objects he was in front of.

Comment: I find it kind of funny that XOR worked so well in my QBASIC stick fighting game, but that there are issues with DRAWING AND ERASING A CIRCLE twelve years later...

Comment: Yes, I remember XOR-ing with GDI a long while back--it was simple and effective.  I guess that's "progress"!  Canvas is a different animal.  You will probably find that erasing/redrawing your entire scene is best for all but the most performance intensive projects.  For ultimate performance you can redraw portions of the canvas or use a second hidden "buffer" canvas which holds your next frame.  Then just draw your buffer to the display canvas and start the whole process over again by drawing on the buffer.

Comment: BTW, you can have 2 overlapping canvas's.  Your background canvas will be under your "animation" canvas.  That way, you can erase the circle on the animation canvas without having to redraw any background.

Comment: Great suggestion. If the rest of the objects are on the upper layer that sounds much less intensive. RE: drawing a 'buffer' canvas, do you know of any sites with instructions on such a technique?

Comment: Here's a fairly good article: http://blog.bob.sh/2012/12/double-buffering-with-html-5-canvas.html   One update to that article:  Canvas will *automatically* "buffer" your drawings starting with "beginPath" and ending with the first fill or stroke.  If you can do all your draws for the next frame before calling fill/stroke...you're being automatically buffered!

Comment: Thanks so much for taking some time to help me with this, @markE !

Comment: I too was astounded that XOR doesn't work as well as it did in 1980!  But on the other hand, drawing is so fast now, probably people figured it wasn't needed.