# Why can't I remove a dashed circle (arc) by drawing it twice with ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";?

Tags: javascript, canvas, xor, custom-painting

I want to make a dashed circle on a canvas in pure JavaScript, that moves to follow the mouse pointer. The circle has no (solid) fill. I thought that by just painting over it again with `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";` would remove it, but that does not work. Why not? Do I now need to invalidate an entire bounding rectangle?

```
let g_ctx = undefined;

function drawCircle(ctx, x, y) {
    const radius = 50;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    //ctx.setLineDash([3, 3]);
    ctx.stroke();

    // This will be removed, but shows the 'xor'-paint in action.
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
} // drawCircle

function onClick(event) {
    drawCircle(g_ctx, 300, 200); // remove circle does not work.
    // Can I use 'this' in onClick or some member of event, 
    // so I won't need g_ctx???
}

const onLoad = function() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";
    g_ctx = ctx;
    canvas.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
    drawCircle(ctx, 300, 200);
}

window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);
```

In html:

```
<body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
```

I had hoped that when the circle is drawn for the 2nd time (or an even number of times) with xor-paint, right on top of the old one, that it would effectively be removed, showing the original background.

I need to remove the circle and redraw it on a new position when the mouse moves. (I will work on handling mouse moves later).

Comment: If it helps, for my solution it is acceptable if the circle is drawn without anti-aliasing. So just pure red pixels and no transparency or lighter red shaded pixels is fine.

Comment: I found the issue may be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740208/drawing-in-javascript-html5-using-xor-to-remove-old-sprite?rq=1